# How to run bash script in python using Airflow

Tags: python, bash, airflow

I have a python function

```py
def running_dump():
    with open('dags/scripts/shell_scripts/daily_pg_dump.sh', 'rb') as file:
        script = file.read()
        print(script)
    subprocess.call(script, shell=True)
```

and a shell file **daily_pg_dump.sh**

```sh
PGPASSWORD='*******' pg_dump -h ***** -p ***** -U ***** -d * -t table_1 > dags/data_bucket/table_1_backup.sql
```

Airflow Dag

```py
pg_dump_to_storage = PythonOperator(
        task_id='task_1',
        python_callable=running_dump,
        dag=dag
    )
```

When I call the python function using Airflow, the shell script seems not to run because **table_1_backup.sql** is not created.
Instead I'm getting **Returned value was: 0** but no error appear. What I'm I missing?

Comment: Tagentially, why are you reading the script into a variable? As binary? You should simply `subprocess.call(['dags/scripts/shell_scripts/daily_pg_dump.sh'])` though I don't think this will solve your problem (nor can we tell you why it failed without more debugging information from your system).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run bash scripts from Airflow, you can use `BashOperator` instead of `PythonOperator`.

From this [example](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/bash.html?highlight=bashoperator#:%7E:text=t2%20%3D%20BashOperator(%0A%20%20%20%20task_id%3D%22bash_example%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20This%20fails%20with%20%27Jinja%20template%20not%20found%27%20error%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20bash_command%3D%22/home/batcher/test.sh%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%23%20This%20works%20(has%20a%20space%20after)%0A%20%20%20%20bash_command%3D%22/home/batcher/test.sh%20%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20dag%3Ddag%2C%0A)) in the documentation, in your case it would be:

```py
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

running_dump = “path/to/daily_pg_dump.sh ” # note the space after the script's name

pg_dump_to_storage = BashOperator(
   task_id='task_1', 
   bash_command=running_dump,
   dag=dag,
)
```

NOTE: You only need the [space](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/bash.html?highlight=bashoperator#:%7E:text=Add%20a%20space%20after%20the%20script%20name%20when%20directly%20calling%20a%20Bash%20script%20with%20the%20bash_command%20argument.) after the script's path name when you are NOT using [templating](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/operator/bash.html?highlight=bashoperator#templating) in your bash script.